How to add role parameter in my response body?
When I Login I cannot add role parameter in my response body.
This is my current response body
{ "tokenType": "string", "accessToken": "string", "expiresIn": 0, "refreshToken": "string" },
I want to create this
{ "tokenType": "string", "accessToken": "string", "expiresIn": 0, "refreshToken": "string", "role":"client" }
I tried this.
My Login method
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginRequest request)
 {
     var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(request.Email);
     if (user == null)
     {
         throw new Exception("Invalid user!");
     }
     var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(request.Email, request.Password,false, false);
     if (!result.Succeeded)
     {
         throw new Exception("Invalid result");
     }
     var role = await GetUserRole(user);
     CreateProperties(role);
     return Ok(role);;
 }

 private async Task<string> GetUserRole(User user)
 {
     
     var rolename = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
     return rolename.FirstOrDefault();
 }
 private static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userRole)
 {
     IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
     {
         { "userRole", userRole }
     };
     return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
 }


Usually this sort of thing would be added as a claim to your JWT.

Update the Response Model:
public class LoginResponse
{
    public string TokenType { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}

Update the Login Method
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginRequest request)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(request.Email);
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid user!");
    }

    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(request.Email, request.Password, false, false);
    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid credentials");
    }

    var role = await GetUserRole(user);

    // Generate token and refresh token (this is just a placeholder, implement your token generation logic here)
    var tokenType = "Bearer";
    var accessToken = "generated_access_token";
    var expiresIn = 3600; // token expiration time in seconds
    var refreshToken = "generated_refresh_token";

    var response = new LoginResponse
    {
        TokenType = tokenType,
        AccessToken = accessToken,
        ExpiresIn = expiresIn,
        RefreshToken = refreshToken,
        Role = role


I tried this, but not working.
